# Display tick and cross icons for a property in the Django administration console

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the Django admin if the field is a BooleanField or NullBooleanField, Django will display a pretty "on" or "off" icon instead of True or False.

Now, I don't really have a BooleanField in my model by I do have a property fior which I'd like to display the icons but when I try doing so, Django screams that `'SomeAdmin.list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_activated' which does not refer to a Field.`

Is it possible to display those nice little icons for this field without hacking Django too much.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't want to use `list_filter`. The property you're looking for is [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). The documentation offers an example of how you can create a column that behaves like a boolean in the display. In short, you do something like this:

1. Create a method in the class:

   ```
   def is_activated(self)
       if self.bar == 'something':
           return True
       return False
   ```
2. add the `.boolean` method attribute directly below the `is_activated` method:

   ```
   is_activated.boolean = True
   ```
3. Add the method as a field in `list_display`:

   class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ['name', 'is_activated']
4. You'll notice the column name is probably now "Is Activated" or something like that. If you want the column heading to change, you use the `short_description` method attribute:

   ```
   is_activated.short_description = "Activated"
   ```

Comment: I'll add that method attributes like these are a fascination of mine, see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337681/method-attributes-in-django

Comment: HI Jordan, this did it but I was wondering whether I have to have a method in my admin class for each custom property in my model class? The `is_activated` is already declared in my Model. Thanks.

Comment: They can be declared in your model or your `ModelAdmin` class. The documentation I linked to actually states this.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but `def is_activated(self): return self.bar == 'something'` is a bit shorter :)

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to do this now in Django 3.0+ is with [`@admin.display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display).

> ```py
>     @admin.display(
>       boolean=True,
>       ordering='-publish_date',
>       description='Is Published?', 
>     ) 
>     def is_published(self, obj):
>         return obj.publish_date is not None
> ```